# How to add php date in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying embed date with particular format by using php code in variable presentdate like below lines of code

```
var dateFormatPHP = getDateFormat();
var formatToApplyPHP = "";

switch(dateFormatPHP)
{

    case "d-m-Y":
         formatToApplyPHP= "d/m/Y";
    break;

    case "m-d-Y":
        formatToApplyPHP= "m/d/Y";
    break;

    case "Y-m-d":
        formatToApplyPHP= "Y/m/d";
    break;

 }     


var presentdate = <?php echo date(formatToApplyPHP);?>
```

Please help !!!

Comment: `formatToApplyPHP` is a JS variable, you cannot use it in PHP as that runs on the server. Your logic here needs to b entirely moved to either the client or the server, you cannot do a hybrid of the two in the manner you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript data transfer to PHP is usually handle with `XmlhttpRequest` ,so create php file eg.date.php ! Send that format as param to that file and get response data . Like this example

```
var dateFormatPHP = getDateFormat();
var formatToApplyPHP = "";

switch(dateFormatPHP)
{

    case "d-m-Y":
         formatToApplyPHP= "d/m/Y";
    break;

    case "m-d-Y":
        formatToApplyPHP= "m/d/Y";
    break;

    case "Y-m-d":
        formatToApplyPHP= "Y/m/d";
    break;

 }     

 $.get("date.php",{d:formatToApplyPHP},function(data) {
      console.log(data);
 });
```

#### date.php

```
<?php
   echo date($_GET['d']);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

formatToApplyPHP is Javascript variable, try to set this variable using PHP, then you can use this statement:

```
var presentdate = <?php echo date($formatToApplyPHP);?>
```